# jquery - .slideToggle() First Click doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have a button that is used to expand a hidden div (hidden using display:none;) using jquery's slideToggle() function. The code is as follows:

```
<button class="mobileonly singlebutton" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:20px;" title="Expand Menu" onclick="$('#menuslide').slideToggle('fast');">Quick Links Menu</button>
<br />
<div id="menuslide" class="infodiv mobileonly" style="display:none; list-style:none; font-size:24px;">
```

The first click doesn't slide the div out, it instead just displays the info. Not only that, but the "infodiv" class style isn't applied. Then when I click it again, it slides out (even though it was already out, it behaves as though it was in) and the "infodiv" class style is applied. So this only happens the first time. Why?

EDIT: I just realized I was running jQuery 1.7.2, so I updated to jQuery 1.9.1 and the behaviour has improved. The first click still doesn't perform as expected, but the second click now brings it back up (recognizing that it was expanded).
I'm testing this in mobile Safari on iPhone.

EDIT2: The following is the CSS that is applied to the div

```
.infodiv
{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-o-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
width:480px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #888888;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #888888;
color:#000000;
padding:3px;
}
.mobileonly
{
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
}
@media only screen /* only for mobile devices apply the following */
and (max-width : 550px)
{
.mobileonly
{
    display:inline;
    visibility:visible;
}

.infodiv
{
    width:400px;
    font-size:14pt;
}
}
```

The id on the div is only used for the javascript, it does not have any style.

Comment: It is working in the fiddle I created. Can you create a fiddle that shows this behavior? http://jsfiddle.net/k3YpW/

Comment: Please provide information about jQuery version and your browser.

Comment: See my edit for the requested details.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik Your fiddle made me realize I was on an old version of jQuery. I'd have to recreate much of the site to put it into a fiddle. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Just curious, if you remove the onclick="" and perform your bind in the $(document).ready(), does that fix it?

Comment: Looks like the problem in styles, which can't be applied to markup when you click first time. The second click fixes styles so it works.

Comment: I think it should work fine with jquery 1.7.2 also.

Comment: Since it does elsewhere on my page, I would think so too. I figured no harm in updating the version, though.

Comment: As mentioned by @Warlock it seems than that it could be problem with the style settings. Can you please show the style settings of the classes and id you have?

Comment: I totally missed Warlock and @Mike C. comments, I'll give those some thought. I've updated the question anyway to add the styles from the stylesheet.

Comment: @MikeC. How would it be performed on click then?

Comment: It pretty much works the same. Make sure it's not styles as Warlock has mentioned, if it isn't I'll post some jquery for you to illustrate. It's easy tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the css. It sure is a CSS issue. I see that you have set `display:inline;` for class `.mobileonly`. Changing it to `display: block;` should solve your problem.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3YpW/2/)

Answer (score 1):

A close `</div>` tag was absent.

```
<div id="menuslide" class="infodiv mobileonly" style="display:none; list-style:none; font-size:24px;">
</div>
```

Comment: I just realized that and added it, but it unfortunately didn't fix the problem.